# Ошибка 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Появляется ошибка 'NoneType' object is not iterable при выполнении этого кода:

```py
message=str(event.obj.message['text'])
ver=5.103
chat_id=str(event.obj.message['peer_id']-2000000000)
errors_count=0

def update_json(keyword, val, mode):
    global hb_bot_ans_file, errors_count, hb_bot_ans
    update_in={keyword: val}
    hb_bot_ans_file.close()
    try:
        if mode == 'update':
            ra_kw='Added new keyword:'
            ra_kwerr='Could not add new keyword: '
        if mode == 'remove':
            ra_kw='Removed keyword:'
            ra_kwerr='Could not remove keyword: '
        hb_bot_ans_file=open('{0}hb_bot_ans.json'.format(data_dir), 'r+')
        hb_bot_ans=dict(json.load(hb_bot_ans_file))
        if mode == 'update':
            hb_bot_ans=dict(hb_bot_ans.update(update_in))
            print(hb_bot_ans)
        if mode == 'remove':
            hb_bot_ans=dict(hb_bot_ans.pop(keyword, None))
            print(hb_bot_ans)
        hb_bot_ans_file.truncate(0)
        hb_bot_ans=dict(json.dumps(hb_bot_ans, indent=4))
        json.dump(hb_bot_ans, hb_bot_ans_file)
        vkg.messages.send(chat_id=chat_id, random_id=functions.get_random_id(), message='{0}\n{1}'.format(ra_kw, update_in), v=ver)
        hb_bot_ans_file.close()
    except Exception as error_message:
        logging.error(error_message)
        errors_count+=1
        vkg.messages.send(chat_id=chat_id, random_id=functions.get_random_id(), message='{0}{1}'.format(ra_kwerr, error_message), v=ver)

if message.startswith('hb add '):
    messagehb=message[7:]
    if r' \|/ ' in messagehb:
        messagehb=messagehb.split(r' \|/ ', -1)
        keyword=str(messagehb[0])
        val=str(messagehb[1])
        update_json(keyword, val, 'update')
    else:
        vkg.messages.send(chat_id=chat_id, random_id=functions.get_random_id(), message='Error, you must split keyword and keyword_answer', v=ver)
```

Как это исправить?

edit: трэйсбэк:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/LigeZet/VkBot/test.py", line 215, in <module>
    update_json(keyword, val, 'update')
  File "/home/LigeZet/VkBot/test.py", line 148, in update_json
    hb_bot_ans=dict(hb_bot_ans.update(update_in))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Где-то я это уже видел... Вам в прошлый раз советовали, но я сделаю это ещё раз — уберите `try-except` в **таком** виде и приведите `Traceback` с ошибкой. В противном случае помочь Вам будет крайне сложно.

Comment: Привел трэйсбэк с ошибкой, смотрите

Comment: Видимо, переменная `hb_bot_ans` указывает на словарь. Метод `update` словаря возвращает `None`. Попытка передать `None` конструктору словаря закономерно приводит к ошибке. Какой цели служит конструкция `hb_bot_ans=dict(hb_bot_ans.update(update_in))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы неправильно обновляете словарь `hb_bot_ans`:

```py
hb_bot_ans = dict(hb_bot_ans.update(update_in))  # hb_bot_ans.update() is None
```

Вызов метода `update` возвращает `None`, и выражение `dict(None)` вызывает ошибку. Достаточно просто вызвать метод, так как словарь — изменяемый объект.

***Пример:***

```py
hb_bot_ans.update(update_in)
```